# vbs script that modifies a accdb database table with the current PC's serial number, user name, and time

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, ms-access-2007, wmi

I am looking to make a logon script for end user's PCs that will do the following in a table (named hardware) in an accdb file:

1. if the table does not contain their serial #, make a new record with the serial # of the PC, current date and time, and the user's logon name.
2. if the table already has a record that matches their serial number, update the existing date and time, and the logon name.

I was able to make this work with the following code, but the only problem is that I have to manually set the serial # in this line of the script

```
strSearchCriteria = "serial = '9BFD9A5'"
```

Here is the whole thing:

```
DateInfo = DateInfo & Now
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adUseClient = 3
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objConnection.Open _
"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
"Data Source = \\server\Inventory.accdb"
objRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient

objRecordset.Open "SELECT * FROM Hardware" , objConnection, _
    adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
objRecordset.MoveFirst
strSearchCriteria = "serial = '9BFD9A5'"
objRecordSet.Find strSearchCriteria
If objRecordset.EOF Then 
    Wscript.Echo "Record cannot be found."
Set colBios = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Bios")
For Each objBios in colBios
    objRecordset.AddNew
    objRecordset("Serial") = objBios.SerialNumber
Next
'
Set colNetworkLoginProfile = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_NetworkLoginProfile")
For Each ObjNetworkLoginProfile in colNetworkLoginProfile
    objRecordset("logonid") = objNetworkLoginProfile.Caption

Next
    objRecordset("logondate") = DateInfo
    objRecordset.Update


Else
    Wscript.Echo "Record found."
    Set colBios = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Bios")
For Each objBios in colBios

    objRecordset("Serial") = objBios.SerialNumber

Next
'
Set colNetworkLoginProfile = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_NetworkLoginProfile")
For Each ObjNetworkLoginProfile in colNetworkLoginProfile
    objRecordset("logonid") = objNetworkLoginProfile.Caption

Next
    objRecordset("logondate") = DateInfo
    objRecordset.Update

End If
objRecordset.Close
objConnection.Close
```

I would like to set it to where the serial # that it searches for in the database is the serial number of the machine that the script is being run on. Seems easy enough but I am a novice.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is to query the SerialNo before you filter the recordset. Then you can use it as criteria for filtering the recordset. 
I modified your code and highlighted the important changes. I too the liverty to restructure the code a bit to remove the duplications.

```
DateInfo = DateInfo & Now
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adUseClient = 3
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objConnection.Open _
"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
"Data Source = \\server\Inventory.accdb"

SerialNo = ""
LogonId = ""

' Get the SerialNo first
Set colBios = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Bios")
For Each objBios in colBios
    SerialNo = objBios.SerialNumber
Next

Set colNetworkLoginProfile = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_NetworkLoginProfile")
For Each ObjNetworkLoginProfile in colNetworkLoginProfile
    LogonId = objNetworkLoginProfile.Caption
Next

objRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient
objRecordset.Open "SELECT * FROM Hardware" , objConnection, _
    adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
objRecordset.MoveFirst
' Now use the Serial to filter the recordset
strSearchCriteria = "serial = '" & SerialNo &  "'"
objRecordSet.Find strSearchCriteria

If objRecordset.EOF Then 
    Wscript.Echo "Record cannot be found."
    objRecordset.AddNew
    objRecordset("Serial") = SerialNo
Else
    Wscript.Echo "Record found."
    ' Serial does not need to be set, we just found it.
End If

objRecordset("logonid") = LogonId
objRecordset("logondate") = DateInfo
objRecordset.Update

objRecordset.Close
objConnection.Close
```

Comment: thank you so much. this worked great. I actually did have a version of the script where I did query the serial # at the beginning, but my script tried calling the variable incorrectly:

`strSearchCriteria = "serial = objItem.SerialNumber"`

i went back and stuck your syntax in and my script (seems to be) working fine now too

`strSearchCriteria = "serial = '" & SerialNo &  "'"`


but I will use your fully modified script because it is much more elegant. thank you so much